# What is the meaning of this malloc error? Corrupted top size?

Tags: c

I'm trying to initialize some values in couple of structs I created. (the goal of the program is to simulate virtual memory) For some reason when I try to initalize `pgTable[i].validFlag = 1` I get this error:

> malloc(): corrupted top size

but not if I initialize it to 0. I thought this had something to go with me going off the end of my array but I don't see how that's possible.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
  int* memmory = malloc( sizeof( int ) * sizeVM * pageSize );
  struct TLBentry* tlb = malloc( sizeof(struct TLBentry) * sizeTLB );
  struct pageTableEntry* pgTable = malloc( sizeof(struct pageTableEntry) * sizeVM );

  for( int i = 0; i < sizeTLB; i++){
    tlb[i].virtualAddress = i;
    tlb[i].physicalAddress = i;
  }

  for( int i = 0; i < sizePM; i++){
    pgTable[i].dirty = 0;
    pgTable[i].validFlag = 1;
    pgTable[i].physicalAddress = i;
  }

  memSys->virtMem = memmory;
  memSys->tlb = tlb;
  memSys->pgTable = pgTable;
```

Comment: TLDR:  Your code corrupted memory.  Full comment:  Just about any error received when you access dynamic memory with functions like `malloc()` and `free()` and all related functions is because of earlier undefined behavior from overrunning a buffer or calling `free()` more than once on a pointer, or by calling `free()` with an improper value.  The earlier corrupting call(s) and/or code set the land mine, and the one you get the error from stepped on it.

Comment: You have some kind of memory corruption bug, possibly _nowhere near_ the code you showed us. Run your program under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org), fix the _first_ invalid memory access it complains about (all subsequent complaints may just be "fallout" from the first error), repeat until no more errors.  If you do not understand how the code fingered by the _first_ invalid memory access could be wrong, cut _that part of the code_ down into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); if you don't discover the problem in the process, ask a new question and provide us the MCVE.

Comment: Additional tip: if `valgrind`'s first complaint appears to be about a C library function, such as `strcpy`, this usually means the bug is in the code that called that function.  `valgrind`'s complaints include a stack trace, so use that to identify the part of your code that is responsible.

Comment: When you loop through a structure, check that the loop limit is the same as the allocation size. Of course we all make mistakes and sometimes get this wrong, but when you actually get an error message, it's a good idea to triple check that you used the same limit in both places -- that's how to see that it is possible that `sizePM` is not the same as `sizeVM`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your loop goes up to `sizePM` while you allocate `sizeVM` entries.